# Query with recursion fails after changing from MYSQL 5.6 to MariaDB 10.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table:

```
Language:
    Seq INT | ParentLanguageSeq INT | Name VarChar
    -------------------------------------------------
    0       | NULL                  | English
    1       | 0                     | English (UK)
    2       | 1                     | English (Irish)
```

And a query:

```
SET @searchSEQ = 2;
SELECT
    l.seq,
    @pv := l.parentlanguageseq parentlanguageseq,
    l.name
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM `language` ORDER BY seq DESC
) as l
JOIN
(
    select @pv := @searchSEQ
) tmp
WHERE
    l.seq = @pv;
```

In MYSQL 5.6 the query would return all three rows with `searchSeq` set to `2`.

```
Seq INT | ParentLanguageSeq INT | Name VarChar
-------------------------------------------------
2       | 1                     | English (Irish)
1       | 0                     | English (UK)
0       | NULL                  | English
```

If the `searchSeq` was set to `1` it would return two rows.

```
Seq INT | ParentLanguageSeq INT | Name VarChar
-------------------------------------------------
1       | 0                     | English (UK)
0       | NULL                  | English
```

If the `searchSeq` was set to `0` it would return two rows.

```
Seq INT | ParentLanguageSeq INT | Name VarChar
-------------------------------------------------
0       | NULL                  | English
```

However, in MariaDB 10 it only returns the row with English (Irish) instead of all three. When `searchSeq` is set to `2`.

```
Seq INT | ParentLanguageSeq INT | Name VarChar
-------------------------------------------------
2       | 1                     | English (Irish)
```

How do I do this in MariaDB 10.1?

Comment: Upgrade to 10.2 and use a "recursive CTE" instead of the kludge that you discovered.  Probably the kludge _happens_ to work in MySQL but not MariaDB.  It is _not_ guaranteed to work.

Comment: I dont have that option... Our webhost decided to migrate our server and changed database versions on us. But I have no control over the version.